# JMSSerializerBundle doctrine entitie update

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have a problem with deserialized Doctrine entities. Serialized objects don't have all fields of the entity and when I update them so that fields are set to null.
I think the same issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726611/how-to-update-a-doctrine-entity-from-a-serialized-json) but there is no solution related to using of JMSSerializer + Doctirne.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you add to your annotations the `@Expose`? Sth like that

```
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Accessor;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Type;

class MyEntity {
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @Expose
     * @Type("integer")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

Comment: Hi Max. Sure - i have in my entity `@ExclusionPolicy('all')` and i set with `@Expose` what should be serialized. Problem is when i deserialize entity i have some null fields which on flush will be nulled in db. 
For example User entity - it would be stupid if i send salt or password in json/xml but if someone try to edit user through rest that fields will be set to null.

Comment: Have you found solution of this problem?