# JMSSerializerBundle, MongoDB, and XML Metadata

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle, doctrine-odm, jmsserializerbundle

I've been wracking my brain over this all night it seems. Every time I try to serialize the results from a document query, I receive a result of **bool(false)**. Presumably this means that the serialization is failing (*great! Perhaps you'd be willing to tell me why you're failing? No? didn't think so.*)

I have told the `JMSSerializerBundle` where my `FOSUserBundle` mappings are held, e.g.:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        file_cache:
            dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            FOSUserBundle:
                namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                path: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/serializer/fosuser"
```

I've defined a very simple XML serializer metadata file, e.g. **Model.User.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<serializer>
    <class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" xml-root-name="user" exclusion-policy="all">
        <property name="username" type="string" expose="true" />
    </class>
</serializer>
```

And, in a test controller I'm manually invoking the serializer before I attempt to do anything more sophisticated, e.g.:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function serializeAction()
    {
        $userManager = // get the user manager
        $users = $userManager->findUsers();         
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
        foreach ($users as $id => $user) {
            Debug::dump('Processing user: '.$user->getUsername());
            $result = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
            Debug::dump($result);
        }
        /*return a response */
    }
}
```

The result? Always **bool(false)**.

However, if I manually construct a new `User` object, the serialization works fine, e.g.:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function serializeAction()
    {
        $userManager = // get the user manager
        $users = $userManager->findUsers();         
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername('testusername');
        Debug::dump('Processing user: '.$user->getUsername());
        $result = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
        Debug::dump($result);
        /*return a response */
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? I'm about ready to lose my mind over this.

**EDIT:** Also on further reflection, it is worth noting that it doesn't look like my serialization metadata is being respected. As shown above I'm only exposing the username, but when I create a new `User` in the controller and serialize it I see more than just that exposed, I'm seeing: `username`, `enabled`, `locked`, `expired`, `roles`, and `credentials_expired`. I suspect that I would be seeing every field, if it had non-null data in it.

**EDIT (2):** I've seen references to using the `DoctrineObjectConstructor` over the default object constructor for the `serializer`; and took the steps identified in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17327855/657674) hoping that they might resolve my issue. Alas, they didn't (looks like that answer and question were more for deserialization though any way) and the result of a **bool(false)** persists.

**EDIT (3):** The issue wherein the serialization metadata was not being picked up, appears to be due to the mixing of `auto_detection` and the explicit declaration of `directories`, as illustrated in another question I've asked: [JMSSerializerBundle mixing auto detection and explicit directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796755/jmsserializerbundle-mixing-auto-detection-and-explicit-directories)

Comment: how do you try to get the usermanager? can you confirm findUsers() does really return a collection of User entities in your controller?

Comment: have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @nifr The issue is still occurring, my user manager is overloaded so I just obtain it via the container, e.g. `$this->get('my.user.doctrine.user_manager')` and, yes, it does return a cursor over the users found. If I don't attempt to serialize the data, and instead just dump the result of the user as I iterate over cursor I see the user data returned.