# JMSSerializerBundle mixing auto detection and explicit directories?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

Is it possible to use `auto_detection` for some bundles, while overriding the location of third-party models by specifying `directories` for them?

I've been playing with the [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) the past couple of days trying to understand it and get it to work with a personal project, and it doesn't look like there is any way to use `auto_detection` as well as specify `directories` for third-party metadata.

If I write my [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/) `Model.User.yml` serialization data, e.g.:

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    access_type: property
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    xml_root_name: user
    properties:
        username:
            type:     string
            expose:   true
```

And place it in the directory specified, while `auto_detection` is set to true, like so:

```
jms_serializer:
  metadata:
    debug: true
    file_cache:
      dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
    auto_detection: true
    directories:
      FOSUserBundle:
        namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
        path: "@MyBundle/config/serializer/fosuser"
```

The serialization metadata is not picked up.

However, if I place the same metadata file under **FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/serializer** (in the vendor bundle) and change the configuration to:

```
jms_serializer:
  metadata:
    debug: true
    file_cache:
      dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
    auto_detection: true
    #directories:
    #  FOSUserBundle:
    #    namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
    #    path: "@MyBundle/config/serializer/fosuser"
```

The serialization metadata is read and properly applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in the directory path, it should have read:

```
jms_serializer:
  metadata:
    debug: true
    file_cache:
      dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
    auto_detection: true
    directories:
      FOSUserBundle:
        namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
        path: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/serializer/fosuser"
```

Took me digging into the `FileLocator` to understand why the file was not being loaded.

Comment: For future me, check in findFileForClass inside Meta\Driver\FileLocator class

Answer (score 1):

Modifying files in the vendors directory is a very bad practice. What you are looking for is answered here:

[JMSSerializerBundle. no control over third party meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960141/jmsserializerbundle-no-control-over-third-party-meta-data)

Kinda late though :p